# Show all event triggers in a database in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, eventtrigger

If we query pg_trigger then we don't get the event triggers, we get list of only normal triggers.

So, is there any other specific table where we can check the event triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are available in system table [pg_event_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-event-trigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can show all user-defined event triggers in the current database:

```
\dy
```

And, this can show all user-defined event triggers in the current database in detail:

```
\dy+
```

And, you can show all user-defined event triggers in the current database with [pg_event_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-event-trigger.html) as shown below. *There is no way to show all event triggers in all databases at once:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger;
```